# vqmod and replacing code within a php if statement

Tags: php, xml, opencart

I'm trying to create a vqmod file that replaces some text within an if statement (catalog/view/theme/themename/template/product/product.tpl):

```
<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl">
  <operation>
    <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<a href="#tab-related"><?php echo $tab_related; ?> (<?php echo count($products); ?>)</a>]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[<a href="#tab-related" class="testing"><?php echo $tab_related; ?> (<?php echo count($products); ?>)</a>]]></add>
  </operation>      
</file>
```

It seems that if a line of code is within an if statement, vqmod does not replace it. But this is not stated in the [vqmod scripting wiki](https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/wiki/Scripting). Am I wrong here? Or am I missing something?

Either way, is there some way I can get this vqmod to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl">
  <operation>
    <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<a href="#tab-related">]]></search>
    <add><![CDATA[<a href="#tab-related" class="testing">]]></add>
  </operation>      
</file>
```

You don't need to match the whole line. You can simply match the opening `<a>` tag like I have above

Comment: Thanks Jay. I swear I tried this, but obviously I didn't (or didn't try it properly), but it works fine now.

Comment: May be worth re-writing the article and adding comments about vQmod or showing us how to do vQmod? Would be a good answer save other people from asking about vQmod and OpenCart